# How can I show blog post excerpts on main page without them disappearing?

Tags: gatsby

When I open the main page of my Gatsby site the excerpts of the second and third blog posts disappear.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Create new project using `gatsby-starter-blog` starter

   ```sh
   gatsby new new-blog https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog
   ```
2. [Add HTML excerpt to blog post](https://github.com/romach/gatsby-example/commit/4e647d5b7ce1581257a2d91c173f7da64fff89f5)
3. Build and serve site

   ```sh
   gatsby build
   gatsby serve
   ```
4. Open url `http://localhost:9000/`
5. Excerpts in second and third blog posts disappear
6. After page reloading excerpts appear
7. The bug can be reproduced again after clearing the page cache (Cmd+Shift + R in Google Chrome) or after opening the page in incognito tab

**Demo:** [Netlify](https://quizzical-curran-ed32a5.netlify.com/)

**Source code:** [Github](https://github.com/romach/gatsby-example)

#### Expected result

Excerpts should be displayed

#### Actual result

Excerpts in second and third blog posts disappeared

**Video**
[image: Screen recording of the bug]

#### Environment

`gatsby info --clipboard`

```
System:
    OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
    Shell: 4.4.19 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 8.16.0 - /usr/bin/node
    npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.15 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 74.0.3729.131
    Firefox: 66.0.5
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.9.4 => 2.9.4
    gatsby-image: ^2.1.4 => 2.1.4
    gatsby-plugin-feed: ^2.2.3 => 2.2.3
    gatsby-plugin-google-analytics: ^2.0.21 => 2.0.21
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.1.1 => 2.1.1
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^2.1.3 => 2.1.3
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.0.12 => 3.0.12
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.1.5 => 2.1.5
    gatsby-plugin-typography: ^2.2.13 => 2.2.13
    gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files: ^2.0.13 => 2.0.13
    gatsby-remark-images: ^3.0.16 => 3.0.16
    gatsby-remark-prismjs: ^3.2.11 => 3.2.11
    gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe: ^2.1.1 => 2.1.1
    gatsby-remark-smartypants: ^2.0.9 => 2.0.9
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.0.39 => 2.0.39
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^2.3.12 => 2.3.12
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.1.21 => 2.1.21
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.6.5
```